# How do I clone a JavaScript object from PascalCase properties to camelCase properties (in JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

When I serialize an ASP.NET MVC form, I get this:

```
{
  DestinationId: "e96dd00a-b042-41f7-bd59-f369904737b6",
  ...
}
```

But I want this, so that it's consistent with JS coding conventions:

```
{
  destinationId: "e96dd00a-b042-41f7-bd59-f369904737b6",
  ...
}
```

How do I take an object and lower-case the first character of each property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also have to check for hasOwnProperty, and remove the previous property

```
var object = { DestinationId: "e96dd00a-b042-41f7-bd59-f369904737b6" }
for ( var prop in object ) {
  if ( object.hasOwnProperty( prop ) ) {
    object[ prop.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + prop.substring(1) ] = object[ prop ];
    delete object[ prop ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you make checking by hasOwnProperty? Your Object.prototype has additional functionality? If it is so - that no good. You must define your own constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Simple way is make iteration over your object:

```
var newObj = {};
for (var p in o) {
    newObj[p.substring(0,1).toLowerCase()+p.substring(1)] = o[p];
}
```

Comment: May be more elegant solution - replace in JSON string by regexp before converting to JS object.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to treat these things as strings and use Reg exps power ?

`JSON.parse(
   JSON.stringify(z).replace(
        /(\"[^"])([^"]*\"\:)/g, 
        function(all, head, tail) { return head.toLowerCase() + tail; }
   )
)`

Comment: Actually you do not need to the first stringify if it comes as string from the back-end.